# Uncaught TypeError in forum loggin

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am making a forum for a school project, everything works fine, but my error message does no longer show up. The  `}else {
            boxAlertfail.style.display = "block";
            boxAlertfail.innerHTML = "Go away, fail";
        }}"`

ever since I added

```
}else if (arrayAdmins[i].email == inputLoginMail.value
        && arrayAdmins[i].password == inputLoginPassword.value)
    {
```

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"

---

```
function login ()
{

if (checklogin()){
        wallPanel.style.display = "block";
        boxAlert.style.display = "block";
        boxAlert.innerHTML = "Welcome" +  aUsers.value;
        dropMenu.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("signinForm").remove();


    }else {
        boxAlertfail.style.display = "block";
        boxAlertfail.innerHTML = "Go away, fail";
    }}


function checklogin(){

var validLogin = false;
for (var i = 0; i < aUsers.length; i++) {
    if (aUsers[i].email == inputLoginMail.value
        && aUsers[i].password == inputLoginPassword.value)
    {
        validLogin = true;
        break;

    }else if (arrayAdmins[i].email == inputLoginMail.value
        && arrayAdmins[i].password == inputLoginPassword.value)
    {
        validLogin = true;
        break;
    }

}
return validLogin;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are looping over aUsers.length which is longer than arrayAdmins array length.

Should be two separate loops!